# ArangoDB Too many open files

Tags: arangodb

since a few days we encounter a problem with our ArangoDB installation. A few minutes/up to an hour after start up all connections to the database are refused. The arango log file says that there are "Too many open files". A "lsof | grep arango | wc -l" shows that the database has around 50,000 open file handles, which is a lot under the max. allowed by the linux system (around 3m). 
Has anyone an idea where this error comes from?

We are using a Ubuntu Linux with a 3.13 kernel. 30 GB RAM and three cores. The database is still very small with around 1,5m entries and a size of 50GB.

Thx, secana

EDIT:
"netstat -anpt | fgrep 2480" shows:

```
root@syssec-graphdb-001-test:~# netstat -anpt | fgrep 2480
tcp        0      0 10.215.17.193:2480      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN               7741/arangod
tcp        0      0 10.215.17.193:2480      10.215.50.30:53453      ESTABLISHED          7741/arangod
tcp        0      0 10.215.17.193:2480      10.215.50.31:49299      ESTABLISHED          7741/arangod
tcp        0      0 10.215.17.193:2480      10.215.50.30:53155      ESTABLISHED          7741/arangod
```

"ulimit -n" has a result of 1024, so I think that the ~50,000 are all arango processes together.

Last lines in log file before the database died:

```
2015-05-26T12:20:43Z [9672] ERROR cannot open datafile '/data/arangodb/databases/database-235999516/collection-28464454696/datafile-18806474509149.db': 'Too many open files'
2015-05-26T12:20:43Z [9672] ERROR cannot open datafile '/data/arangodb/databases/database-235999516/collection-28464454696/datafile-18806474509149.db': Too many open files
2015-05-26T12:20:43Z [9672] DEBUG [arangod/VocBase/collection.cpp:1632] cannot open '/data/arangodb/databases/database-235999516/collection-28464454696', check failed
2015-05-26T12:20:43Z [9672] ERROR cannot open document collection from path '/data/arangodb/databases/database-235999516/collection-28464454696'
```

Comment: Can you also do a "netstat -anpt | fgrep 8529", where 8529 is the server port?

Comment: What driver are you using to connect to ArangoDB?

Comment: What is the result of `ulimit -n` when run in the same environment as the arangod process (i.e. same shell and user)? It's probably a lot less than the maximum *possible* value. It may help increasing the maximum # of open files via `ulimit` for the arangod process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it will make sense to increase the max. number of open files a process is allowed to manage. Given the stated database size of around 50 GB, the (presumably default) value of 1024 seems to be too low.

*arangod* will require one file descriptor for each parallel client connection. That may not be many, but in the face of HTTP keep-alive connections this could already account for several file descriptors.

Additionally, each datafile of an active collection will need to be memory-mapped and cost one file descriptor as well. With the default datafile size of 32 MB, a database size of 50 GB (on disk) will already consume 1,600 file descriptors:

```
50 GB database size / (32 MB default size / 1 datafile) = 1600 datafiles
```

Increasing the `ulimit -n` value for the *arangod* user and environment therefore will make sense. You can confirm that *arangod* can actually use the configured number of file descriptors by starting it with option `--server.descriptors-minimum <value>`, e.g.

```
--server.descriptors-minimum 32768
```

for that many file descriptors. If *arangod* cannot effectively use that specified amount of file descriptors, it will fail at start with a fatal error. Of course that option can also be put into the `arangod.conf` file.

Additionally, the default size for (new) datafiles can be increased via the `journalSize` parameter for collections. That won't help right now, but will lower the number of required file descriptors for data saved in the future.

Comment: Increasing the ulimit helped, thx. For the long run I increased the jounal size, too.

Comment: Is the datafile size in 2.5.7 version 32mb or more. I have an installation where data files are growing larger than 32mb. One of the collection has 3 large files 182M for compaction, 190M for datafile1 and 182M datafile2. arangod.conf is default and journal file size is set to 32M

Comment: This might happen in two situations: First, if documents bigger than 32M are used, they won't fit into a 32M datafile, so datafiles will dynamically extend in size for these bigger documents. Second, when the compaction processes full datafiles, it may concatenate the remaning contents of a few datafiles together.

Comment: By the way, ArangoDB 2.7 will have adjusted (read: raised) limits value in its start/stop scripts, so there will be less need to adjust the limits manually.

Answer (score 2):

For emergencies when you can't restart the database, like in my case, you will find very useful [this blog post](http://lzone.de/cheat-sheet/ulimit) that explains how you can change the ulimit of a **running** process.

If your distribution has util-linux-2.21, you can use the "[prlimit](http://karelzak.blogspot.de/2012/01/prlimit1.html)" tool, or you can compile the small example C program in the blog post that worked great for me.

To check the actual limits of a process you can use:

`cat /proc/<PID>/limits`

Good luck!